# Heterogeneous environment "roaming" profiles

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, mount, cifs

By "roaming profiles" I really mean "shared home directories".

So, I set up an AD pair, and shared a folder on `\\ad-1\homes`.  Then set the AD user object to mount `H:\ = \\ad-1\homes\%username%`.  This works fine on Windows (as you'd expect).

I also configured Folder Redirection on a GPO on the User's OU to point Documents at `\\ad-1\homes\%username%\Documents` and so on.

Everything works as you'd expect on Windows. Yay.

HOWEVER.

Linux is a different story.  Using Winbind and Samba, I've joined the domain.  No problem.

```
# wbinfo -u
PRODUCT\administrator
PRODUCT\guest
PRODUCT\krbtgt
PRODUCT\aa
PRODUCT\ab
```

I've edited the AD uidNumber and gidNumber so that I get this:

```
# wbinfo -i PRODUCT\\aa
PRODUCT\aa:*:10001:10000:aa:/home/PRODUCT/aa:/bin/bash
```

I naively thought, I'd be able to mount `\\ad-1\homes` onto `/home/$DOMAIN` and as the usernames are the same, i'd be able to use them as home directories.

Except because the cifs share is mounted at boot, as root, the permissions are `dwrxr-x-r-x root root .` all the way down the directory tree, so users can't write to them.

I've tried almost every combination of mount.cifs options, including the promising "`multiuser`", and found best results using `sec=krb5i`.

What I want is to be able to mount the \ad-1\homes directory, on top of /home/$DOMAIN, and have it look like

```
name  owner
aa/ DOMAIN\aa
ab/ DOMAIN\ab
administrator DOMAIN\administrator
```

and so on.

Does anyone know how this is achievable?

Windows 2008 R2, mounting on SLES 11 SP2.

Comment: I'll post a huge bounty for a working solution to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're doing this with our Active Directory domain joined (winbind) Debian boxes.  We use `pam_mkhomedir` to create a home folder under /home/EXAMPLE/$USER for AD users at logon.  Then `pam_mount` performs the mounting of the AD home directory.  On Debian, we needed to install `libpam-mount`, `pam_mkhomedir` was installed by default

Once installed the following files are modified:

/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>
<debug enable="0" />
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other,workgroup,nosetuids,noexec,nosuid" />
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
<logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
<!--
  Replace "fs1.ad.example.com" with your Windows file server.
  We mount our AD user homes under /home/EXAMPLE, change this to suit your needs.
  Edit "workgroup=EXAMPLE" to use your domain/realm.
-->
<volume fstype="cifs" server="fs1.ad.example.com" path="home/%(USER)" mountpoint="/home/EXAMPLE/%(USER)" user="*" options="workgroup=EXAMPLE,uid=%(USER),dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,nosuid,nodev" />
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session:

```
# <snip>
# We use pam to create the AD user home drives
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077
session optional        pam_mount.so nullok try_first_pass
```

For example when I (FCSD\jscott) logon to a Linux box, my AD home folder \\staff\home\jscott is mounted as /home/FCSD/jscott.

[image]

Comment: @TomO'Connor Great, glad it was that simple. Just be aware that with this configuration certain files may behave in slightly unexpected ways.  For instance .bash_history will save entires from each box a user logs onto. Per-user config files may not always be compatiable when on Linux boxes with different app versions.  If this becomes a problem, you can always edit the `mountpoint` option to mount the AD homeDirectory *under* the Linux user's home. *e.g.* /home/DOMAIN/username/AD_home

Comment: .bash_history is a hideous antiquated thing anyway, I tend to implement the http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/543 or similar hack.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done what you're looking for, but I *think* the experimental [CONFIG_CIFS_ACL](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CIFS_ACL.html) if you want to do this with a single mount point. Otherwise, what @jscott is doing should work, albeit each user's home directory is a new mount point and ACLs within the home directory aren't going to work.